# Wrong location listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent, android-recyclerview

So i have recycler view that show json with option to search through that list. Before search when click on specific list item i get new activity that show details about that item. Problem is when i search list and click on item i get wrong detail. Example 
if the result of the search is in the first place(top listview item) when I click on it i get the data from the item that was there before the search. How to fix this?

**DataAdapter.java**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> mArrayList;
    private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> mFilteredList;
    Context ctx;
    private Context context;

    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<AndroidVersion> arrayList, Context ctx,Context context) {
        mArrayList = arrayList;
        mFilteredList = arrayList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view,ctx,mFilteredList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.tv_name.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getName());
        viewHolder.tv_version.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getVer());
        viewHolder.tv_api_level.setText(mFilteredList.get(i).getApi());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = mArrayList;
                } else {

                    ArrayList<AndroidVersion> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (AndroidVersion androidVersion : mArrayList) {

                        if (charString.contains(",")) {
                            String searchChar[] = charString.split(",");
                            for (int i = 0; i < searchChar.length; i++) {

                                if (androidVersion.getApi().toLowerCase().contains(searchChar[i]) || androidVersion
                                        .getName()
                                        .toLowerCase().contains(searchChar[i]) || androidVersion.getVer().toLowerCase()
                                        .contains(searchChar[i])) {

                                    filteredList.add(androidVersion);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (androidVersion.getApi().toLowerCase().contains(charString) || androidVersion.getName()
                                    .toLowerCase().contains(charString) || androidVersion.getVer().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(charString)) {

                                filteredList.add(androidVersion);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<AndroidVersion>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private TextView tv_name,tv_version,tv_api_level;
        ArrayList<AndroidVersion> arrayList = new ArrayList<AndroidVersion>();
        Context ctx;
        public ViewHolder(View view, Context ctx, ArrayList<AndroidVersion> arrayList) {
            super(view);

            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            this.ctx = ctx;
            view.setOnClickListener(this);

            tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            tv_version = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_version);
            tv_api_level = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_api_level);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = getAdapterPosition();
            AndroidVersion arrayList = this.arrayList.get(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.ctx, Details.class);
            intent.putExtra("name_id",arrayList.getName());
            intent.putExtra("version_id",arrayList.getVer());
            intent.putExtra("api_level_id",arrayList.getApi());
            ((Context) this.ctx).startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that "ViewHolder" class is only initialized first time, where you are setting your "ClickListener" to views. But the issue is that you pass your complete array once to "ViewHolder" and didn't pass the filtered array to "ViewHolder", because it is initialized once. So when you get data with position on the click, it's returns you the data from main arraylist and not from the filtered one.

So come to the solution, set your "ClickListener" to view in "onBindViewHolder" method and not in ViewHolder class, because it's called every time when you interact with the list or data changes. Hope it will work for you.